# Target class [set_locale] does not exist. Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10

I'm trying to run Laravel but I get this error "**Target class [set_locale] does not exist.**". This problem appeared when transferring from Laravel 7 to 10. What could this be related to? What files need to be provided to make it clear what the problem is?

**routes web.php**

```
use App\Http\Controllers;
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Auth::routes([
    'reset' => false,
    'confirm' => false,
    'verify' => false,
]);

Route::get('locale/{locale}', 'MainController@changeLocale')->name('locale');
Route::get('currency/{currencyCode}', 'MainController@changeCurrency')->name('currency');
Route::get('/logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('get-logout');

Route::middleware(['set_locale'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('reset', 'ResetController@reset')->name('reset');

    Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function () {
        Route::group([
            'prefix' => 'person',
            'namespace' => 'Person',
            'as' => 'person.',
        ], function () {
            Route::get('/orders', 'OrderController@index')->name('orders.index');
            Route::get('/orders/{order}', 'OrderController@show')->name('orders.show');
        });

        Route::group([
            'namespace' => 'Admin',
            'prefix' => 'admin',
        ], function () {
            Route::group(['middleware' => 'is_admin'], function () {
                Route::get('/orders', 'OrderController@index')->name('home');
                Route::get('/orders/{order}', 'OrderController@show')->name('orders.show');
            });

            Route::resource('categories', 'CategoryController');
            Route::resource('products', 'ProductController');
            Route::resource('products/{product}/skus', 'SkuController');
            Route::resource('properties', 'PropertyController');
            Route::resource('merchants', 'MerchantController');
            Route::get('merchant/{merchant}/update_token', 'MerchantController@updateToken')->name('merchants.update_token');
            Route::resource('coupons', 'CouponController');
            Route::resource('properties/{property}/property-options', 'PropertyOptionController');
        });
    });


    Route::get('/', 'MainController@index')->name('index');
    Route::get('/categories', 'MainController@categories')->name('categories');
    Route::post('subscription/{skus}', 'MainController@subscribe')->name('subscription');

    Route::group(['prefix' => 'basket'], function () {
        Route::post('/add/{skus}', 'BasketController@basketAdd')->name('basket-add');

        Route::group([
            'middleware' => 'basket_not_empty',
        ], function () {
            Route::get('/', 'BasketController@basket')->name('basket');
            Route::get('/place', 'BasketController@basketPlace')->name('basket-place');
            Route::post('/remove/{skus}', 'BasketController@basketRemove')->name('basket-remove');
            Route::post('/place', 'BasketController@basketConfirm')->name('basket-confirm');
            Route::post('coupon', 'BasketController@setCoupon')->name('set-coupon');
        });
    });

    Route::get('/{category}', 'MainController@category')->name('category');
    Route::get('/{category}/{product}/{skus}', 'MainController@sku')->name('sku');
});
```

**kernel.php**

```
namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'is_admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckIsAdmin::class,
        'basket_not_empty' => \App\Http\Middleware\BasketIsNotEmpty::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
        'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
        'set_locale' => \App\Http\Middleware\SetLocale::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The priority-sorted list of middleware.
     *
     * This forces non-global middleware to always be in the given order.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewarePriority = [
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    ];
}
```

**Controllers > middleware SetLocal.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;

class SetLocale
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $locale = session('locale');
        App::setLocale($locale);
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include the full stack trace and any relevant code from your application.

Comment: Did you follow all [upgrade guides](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/upgrade)?

Comment: @brombeer I installed an empty project on Laravel 10 and transferred my data there from the old one

Comment: I'd copy the old L7 project and follow _all_ upgrade guides, 7 to 8, 8 to 9, 9 to 10 in that copy

Comment: @brombeer ohh, there are no other options ?  indicated the files above.

Comment: what do you mean by "Controllers > middleware SetLocal.php" is the SetLocale.php inside the "Controllers" folder ?

Comment: are you sure you moved the `Kernel.php` file over and it isn't the default one that comes with L10? as that error usually means you don't have a middleware by that name defined in the HTTP kernel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed in the files u said

```
routes web.php
```

And then

```
Controllers > middleware SetLocal.php
```

If you mean middleware folder is in Controllers folder ,this is wrong check your namespace

**Also pretty important** your middleware folder should be Middleware

*Remamber case sensitive*